# timestamp check if 10 minutes ago

Tags: php, date

I have a data in a text file saved using  `date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+2 minutes"))` that I need to check if it's 10 minutes ago. I'm trying the following code but it doesn't print anything even if more than 10 minutes ago.

```
  $now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now"));
  if($now > strtotime($old_data))
       echo 'expired!';
```

Comment: Convert them to timestamps, and then test if now is more than 600 seconds after the old timestamp.

Comment: `$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")));` or most likely `if (strtotime($now) > strtotime($old_data))`

Comment: What's in `$old_data? Can you post the code that sets it?

Comment: `strtotime` returns a numeric timestamp, but `date` returns a date time that look like `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. It makes no sense to compare them directly.

Answer (score 14):

your comparing a formatted date with a time stamp which explains why nothing works

here:

```
$now = strtotime("-10 minutes");

if ($now > strtotime($old_data) {
  echo 'expired!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change either of the following:

`$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")));`

or

`if (strtotime($now) > strtotime($old_data))`

I'll go for the second. You are comparing a timestamp over date that is why you are not satisfying the condition of `if()`.

Furthermore, you can also use `time()` if you're only concern is the current timestamp.

`$now = time();`

or

```
$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")); // Remove this line

if(time() > strtotime($old_data)) // Change $now with time()
```